# Iterating through Values of Row from a JOIN of multiple tables PHP/MYSQLi

Tags: php, loops, mysqli, iteration

I  have a JOIN made from multiple tables.

```
$sql_entries = "SELECT transaction_information . *, customer_information . * , property_information . *, borrowers . *,  lenders . *, listing_agents . *, payoff . *,  sellers . *, selling_agents .*
                        FROM transaction_information
                        JOIN customer_information ON transaction_information.entry_no = customer_information.entry_no
                        JOIN property_information ON transaction_information.entry_no = property_information.entry_no
                        JOIN borrowers ON transaction_information.entry_no = borrowers.entry_no
                        JOIN lenders ON transaction_information.entry_no = lenders.entry_no
                        JOIN listing_agents ON transaction_information.entry_no = listing_agents.entry_no
                        JOIN payoff ON transaction_information.entry_no = payoff.entry_no
                        JOIN sellers ON transaction_information.entry_no = sellers.entry_no
                        JOIN selling_agents ON transaction_information.entry_no = selling_agents.entry_no
                       ";
```

It returns around 50+ Columns. I want to display the column names on top and below it the values.

I am trying to use the following code but it's not giving me the desired result.

```
      $result_entries = $conn->query($sql_entries);



                 if ($result_entries->num_rows > 0) {
                    echo '<div id="total"><table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-responsive">';

                    echo "<tr>";
                            //$entries = array();
                        while($row = $result_entries->fetch_assoc()) {



                             foreach ($row as $key => $value) {



                                 echo '<th>'.$key.'</th>';
                            }

                        echo '</tr>';

                        }

                     //ROw of Table heading ends.
      // Fetch values in the columns under the respective heads. 

                        while($row1 = $result_entries->fetch_assoc()) {
                            echo '<tr>';

                             foreach ($row1 as $col) {

                              echo '<td>'.$col.'</td>'; 
//This wil return Object and I know. But I don't want to use   $row['indexName'] and repeat myself for fetching values as there are too many columns.

                            }
                          echo '</tr>';
                        }



                    echo "</table></div>";
                    } else {
                        echo "0 results for Entries";
                    }
```

Okay, my first question will be to iterate over each row value without doing something like $row['indexname']
Second, that my column headings are being repeated twice as well in the same row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) you can get your column names. Then using [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) you can build your header row, with `<th></th>`. To only echo the header row on the first loop, you can use a boolean var, ie. `$header = true;`. Then after echoing the header row set it to false and it won't output again. Your code would look something like -

```
$result_entries = $conn->query($sql_entries);

if ($result_entries->num_rows > 0) {
    echo '<div id="total"><table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-responsive">';

    $headers = true;

    while($row = $result_entries->fetch_assoc()) {

        // echo headers on 1st iteration
        if($headers){
            echo "<tr><th>".implode("</th><th>",array_keys($row))."</th><tr>";
            $headers = false;
        }

        // echo row values
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
            echo "<td>".$value."</td>"; 
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table></div>";
} else {
    echo "0 results for Entries";
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sean. It works great but my Joins are not working properly. It returns multiple rows for 2 entries for borrower section. Here's a link to main form http://208.109.186.112/kushalmn/demo1/. Can you please have a look!